# MVC - How to pass a parameter via constructor

Tags: model-view-controller, ninject

I'm extending the Controller class, and I want into its constructor initiate it with a parameter name Tiposconceptos. Still, I am getting the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Error activating TiposConceptos
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:

2) Injection of dependency TiposConceptos into parameter concepto of constructor of type AccionesController

1) Request for AccionesController

Even it says what I have to do I still don´t get it. I know I have to add something into NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices, but I have not idea what is the line to accomplish what I want to achieve.

the code is as follow:

SecurityController

```
public class SecurityController : Controller
{
    public SecurityController(TiposConceptos concepto)
    {
        GetPermissions(concepto);
    }
```

AccionesController

```
public class AccionesController : SecurityController
{
    public AccionesController(TiposConceptos concepto) : base(concepto)
    {
        concepto = TiposConceptos.Acción;
    }
```

}

Comment: It says it's not self-bindable which usually means that it doesn't have a default constructor and each constructor it has does not have bound or self-bindable parameters. You need to ensure that all parameters in the resolution chain can be resolved by Ninject in order for it to work

Comment: thanks for replying.... but I still don´t get what I must do..